# How to make .exe from Qt with OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, deployment

I have QtProject with some OpenCV used and I want to make .exe from it to run it on other computers.

windeployqt.exe can't do it even for Qt libraries, but if I copied libraries manually Qt is working. But then, I have no idea how to get OpenCV working.
My .pro file looks like this.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator ...
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = name01
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv-qt/install/include
LIBS += -L"C:/opencv-qt/install/x86/mingw/bin"
LIBS += -lopencv_core310 -lopencv_highgui310 -lopencv_imgproc310 -lopencv_imgcodecs310

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h

FORMS    += widget.ui
```

In this case, when I try to run .exe it says that libopencv_imgcodecs310 is missing in my computer.
I guess I have to change paths, so I tried this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /include
LIBS += -L"/bin"
LIBS += -lopencv_core310 -lopencv_highgui310 -lopencv_imgproc310 -lopencv_imgcodecs310
```

and copied bin and include folders to project. But it didn't even compiled with error message

```
cannot find -lopencv_core310
cannot find -lopencv_highgui310
cannot find -lopencv_imgproc310
cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs310
```

I found some questions about it on other forums, but they weren't answered.

I haven't got time, so I came bact to this problem now.
Qt 5.8 was released, which shouldn't be problem, but my application gets bigger and now .pro looks like this:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator ...
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport

TARGET = name01
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv-qt/install/include
LIBS += -L"C:/opencv-qt/install/x86/mingw/bin"
LIBS += -lopencv_core310 -lopencv_highgui310 -lopencv_imgproc310 -lopencv_imgcodecs310

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp\
        qcustomplot.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h
        qcustomplot.h

FORMS    += widget.ui
```

So now it isn't working even on my computer.
If I try to run .exe it is saying:

```
the procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located
in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll
```

I also tried Dependency Walker and it says only that it couldn't find libopencv_imgprocs310.dll, libopencv_core310.dll and libopencv_imgcodecs310.dll even if they are in same folder as .exe.

I don't know how exactly should I now manage the question or if I should make a new one, so sorry for any difficulties.

Comment: Paths starting with `/` are absolute paths. Are you sure you have right `bin` and `include` directories on root folder? Or maybe you mean (for example) `$$PWD/bin` and `$$PWD/include` ?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it means absolute paths. However its same result when I use `$$PWD/include` or just `include`

Comment: I came back to this after long time and I don't know how exactly should I now manage the question or if I should make a new one, so I have changed Question. Sorry for any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

When your OpenCV lib files are still in C:/opencv-qt/install/x86/mingw/bin and your code compile, try to copy the .dll files being used by your code to the folder containing your exe file. Or add C:/opencv-qt/install/x86/mingw/bin to your environmental variables.

Comment: Yes, copying .dll into project folder is working for my computer, but not for others.

Comment: Are you trying to build the same project on other computers or just copying the exe file to other computers and run it there? When you run the exe file, regardless of which computer, it will search for dynamically linked libraries. The directory from which the exe loaded is the first place it looks for. Try put your opencv dll there. Your project folder is not necessarily the folder where the exe is.

Comment: Running it on my computer is no problem, I want to run that .exe on other computers. Even if I copied .dll to to same folder as my .exe is, qt runs well, but OpenCV functions simply do nothing.

Comment: So your exe can run without missing dll problem now, but the expected OpenCV functions are not working?

Comment: Exactly, I even tried to add dlls to path on other computer, but it is still same

Comment: Try Dependency Walker on your exe on the problematic computer, and see what it can find out.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is interested in `.lib` files so you should add the folder containing lib files, not dlls. Dlls are required during execution, so you should copy those into your deployment.

My boiler-plate OpenCV section under windows looks like this (note I like to use `opencv_world` instead of separate modules)

```
win32 {
  OPENCVFOLDER = D:/_CODE_/_EXTERNAL_/OpenCV/my_git_build/
  OPENCVVERSION = 310
  INCLUDEPATH += $${OPENCVFOLDER}/x64/install/include

  CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
      LIBS += -L$${OPENCVFOLDER}/x64/lib/Release
      LIBS += -lopencv_world$${OPENCVVERSION}
  }
  CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
      DEFINES += DEBUG_MODE
      LIBS += -L$${OPENCVFOLDER}/x64/lib/Debug
      LIBS += -lopencv_world$${OPENCVVERSION}d
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me link to, how you installed(added) OpenCV in your Qt Creator, because i have no .lib files in my opencv folder.